# Update Checkbox by checking already existing field values

Tags: apex, trigger, related-list

I'm creating an approval process in an account where I am checking the values of a related list, and if the value equals a certain value, I want to check a checkbox on the account object. I have it working whenever I create a new related list record, but my issue is looking at the field values that are already populated in the related list. I attached my attempt at the trigger below, but I see issues already: It shouldn't be after insert of an account (after update maybe?). Thanks in advance!

```
    trigger UpdateIsShareRefCheckbox on Account (after insert, after update) {

    Set<ID> acctIds = new Set<ID>();

    // Loop through all of the accounts in the old Trigger
    for(Account a : Trigger.old){
        acctIds.add(a.id);
    }

    List<Account> accounts = [SELECT id, is_Share_Ref_Digital__c, is_Share_Ref_USAT__c FROM Account WHERE id IN :acctIds];
    List<Share_Reference__c> srList = [SELECT id, salesTeam__c FROM Share_Reference__c WHERE id IN :acctIds];    


    // Loop through all of the old accounts 
    For(Account ac : accounts){
        //Loop through all of the share_reference reps within those accounts
        for(Share_Reference__c sr : srList){
            // If the Share Reference Rep is on the Digital Sales Teams --> Updated the checkbox is_Share_Ref_Digital__c to true
            if(sr.SalesTeam__c == 'Digital Sales' && ac.is_Share_Ref_Digital__c == false){
                ac.is_Share_Ref_Digital__c = true;
            } else if(sr.SalesTeam__c == 'USAT Integrated Brand Sales' && ac.is_Share_Ref_USAT__c == false){
                ac.is_Share_Ref_USAT__c = true; 
            }
        }
    }
    update accounts;
}
```

Comment: When you say "if the value equals a certain value" do you mean the value of the most recent related record? You have multiple related records on the Account, based on which ones do you want to evaluate?

Comment: I mean the value of the Share_Reference__c object that is related to Account. I want to look through all of the Share_Reference__c Reps to see if the value of Share_Reference__c.SalesTeam__c == 'Digital Sales'  or 'Integrated Brand Sales'.  I was hoping to loop through all of the Share_Reference__c records and compare whether or not they equal that value, but can't get that to work

Comment: When there are multiple records it means that you might have mixed values for that field. Both 'Digital Sales' and 'Integrated Brand Sales' values might be present in the list of records related to the Account. Which one would you chose?

Comment: I have two separate checkboxes on the account object, so that I would be able to update the checkboxes based on if there is a Share_Reference__c with a value of 'Integrated Brand Sales' or 'Digital Sales'. Or if there was one of each, then both boxes could be checked.

Comment: Why don't you create the trigger after insert/update on Share_Reference__c instead?

Comment: It gets a little complicated there. I was hoping there was an easy solution. Big picture: I'm creating an approval process where a rep creates a request, that gets approved by their manager, then if the rep that made the request is part of the same sales team as a rep already on the account then it needs to get that rep managers approval, then it would go to a final manager that would then manually add the rep to the share_reference. If there is not a rep already on the salesteam, then it would go directly to the final approval. So I need the field update before that whole process happens.

Comment: Your trigger checks related records on the Account, you will not have any related records upon insertion of Account, so you can comfortably remove the `after insert` part. Not sure what the problem is with the `after update` part though, it looks right. Also why are you using `trigger.old`?

Comment: Because there are already records in the Share_Reference related list, which are the values I'm really after. I figured with Trigger.new I would only be targeting the new values I would be inserting/updating, which I am already able to do.

Comment: `Trigger.new` or `Trigger.old` will give you the values on the Account fields. In both cases the related list of records will be the same. I'm really confused here. What is the actual problem that you're trying to solve?